# Missing packets error when streaming rtsp to rtmp using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, rtsp, rtmp, sdp

I'm using ffmpeg to do RTSP to RTMP streaming, the input is an sdp file describing one video stream and one audio stream, when I test the RTSP using ffplay,it works fine

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp" -strict -2 -i media.sdp
```

but when I switch to ffmpeg to do streaming, I got lot of packet missing errors

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp" -strict -2  -i media.sdp   -c copy -f flv "rtmp://liveaddress"
```

error log:

```
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] RTP: missed 321 packets
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] max delay reached. need to consume 
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] RTP: missed 14 packets
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 000001f1f4cea400] RTP: missed 7 packets
```

the sdp file:

```
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.12.100
m=video 5555 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
b=AS:2000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAINoBQBbsBagICAoAAAfSAAOpgR4wZUA=,aM4fIA==; profile-level-id=42c020
m=audio 6666 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
b=AS:125
a=rtpmap:96 MPEG4-GENERIC/44100/2
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3; config=1210
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research on the web, I have found a solution:
add a -buffer_size command arg to ffmpeg cause my H264 video from RTSP server has variable bit rate I guess.

Comment: What did you set the value to?

Comment: What did you set the value to?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved with `-rtsp_transport tcp -protocol_whitelist rtp,file,udp,tcp` command line options for ffmpeg